# Querying Ensembl

Tags: python, mysql, search

Is it possible to query all of Ensembl programmatically (preferably python) with free form search terms, similar to what one would do from their web UI? The REST API does not appear to support search term queries at all, and other APIs that interact with the MySQL databases directly, like PyCogent, can only query one species at a time (which makes sense, given the structure of the public MySQL db, but means spamming their server with 40+ requests to search all species...).

What I really want is to be able to do something like the following:

```
session = Connect(Ensembl)
matches_list = session.search("MyPetGene")
```

I suspect this isn't possible, but thought I'd throw it out to the collective brains of the internet before hacking something more complicated.

Comment: what have you [tried](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ensembl&oq=Ensembl&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.662j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#q=Ensembl+advanced+search)

Comment: Drew: Thanks for the Google search suggestion
1) Ensembl Web Code might be usable, but requires I write my own wrappers.
2) PyEnsemble won't work for me because it builds local sqlite databases instead of querying the server directly
3) PyCogent is Python2, and my project is Python3
4) Perl API... Ugh...

Answer (score 1):

Using pymysql to do the query...  This is a code example for people wanting to query the ensembl database.  I appreciate this doesnt directly answer your question, but the ensembl schema is split up into species see https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/api/core/core_schema.html

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host="ensembldb.ensembl.org", user="anonymous", db="homo_sapiens_core_104_38" )
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from gene limit 200;")
myresults = cursor.fetchall()
for x in myresults:
    print(*x)
cursor.close()
db.close()
```